# IF inside FOR loop in Matlab doesn't work

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I have this function below, but the `if` statement inside the `for` loop doesn't work. I tried `<=` instead of `<` and also `round()`, but they didn't work.

```
function points1=tracker(count1,points1,u,v,I2)

for j=1:count1

   if  (points1(1,j) < size(u,1))&&(points1(2,j) < size(u,2))

       points1(1,j)= points1(1,j)+v(points1(1,j),points1(2,j));
       points1(2,j)= points1(2,j)+u(points1(1,j),points1(2,j));
       I2(round(points1(1,j)),round(points1(2,j)))=255;

   else

       points1(:,j)=[];
       count1=count1-1;
       j=j-1;

   end

end

    figure, imshow(I2)

end
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about it?

Comment: Did my answer [solve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to change the increment of the `for` loop, `j`, from within the loop (your `j=j-1` line). You can't do this. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html#bsfxe_m-4) for `for` states:

> Avoid assigning a value to the index variable within the body of a loop. The for statement overrides any changes made to the index within the loop.

You'll need to use a [`while`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) loop instead or find another way of doing what you need using an intermediate variable.